# QML Dynamic Map Object Creation

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I am trying to build interactive map application which will allow me to create an object when I click somewhere on the map. I use [QML Dynamic Object Creation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) to create the object. I have succeeded to create a rectangle (still have coordinate problem), but when I change the rectangle with MapQuickItem or MapCircle, it shows nothing.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "componentCreation.js" as MyScript
import QtQuick.Controls 2.1
import QtLocation 5.3
import QtPositioning 5.2

Window  {
    id: appWindow
    width: 512
    height: 512
    visible: true
    Map {
        id: map
        //width: win.width - kolom.width - row1.spacing
        anchors.fill: parent
        activeMapType: map.supportedMapTypes[2]
        zoomLevel: 1
        //z:1


        center {
            latitude: 5
            longitude: 100
        }
        plugin: Plugin {
            name: 'osm';
            PluginParameter {
                name: 'osm.mapping.offline.directory';
                value: ':/offline_tiles/'
            }
        }
        MapCircle {
            radius: 800000
            color: 'blue'
            center {
                latitude: 5
                longitude: 100
            }
        }

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onPressed: {
                var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
                console.log("coordinate: " + coord)

                //MyScript.createSpriteObjects(map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).latitude,map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y)).longitude)
                MyScript.createSpriteObjects(mouse.x,mouse.y)

            }
        }
    }
}
```

componentCreation.js

```js
var component
var sprite

function createSpriteObjects(posX,posY) {
    component = Qt.createComponent("Sprite.qml");
    if (component.status == Component.Ready)
        finishCreation(posX,posY);
    else
        component.statusChanged.connect(finishCreation);

}

function finishCreation(posX,posY) {
    if (component.status == Component.Ready) {
        //sprite = component.createObject(map, {"marker.coordinate": map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(posX,posY))});
        sprite = component.createObject(map);
        console.log("Object Created " + map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(posX,posY)));
        //sprite = component.createObject(appWindow);
        if (sprite == null) {
            console.log("Error creating Object");
        }
    }
    else if (component.status == Component.Error) {
        console.log("Error loading component:", component.errorString());
    }
}
```

Sprite.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtLocation 5.3


MapQuickItem {
    id: marker
    sourceItem: Image {
        id: image
        source: "marker.png"
    }
    coordinate {
        latitude: 5
        longitude: 100
    }
    anchorPoint.x: image.width / 2
    anchorPoint.y: image.height / 2
    visible: true
}

/*Rectangle {
    width: 100
    height: 20
    x: 10
    y:10
}*/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MapQuickItem` and `MapCircle` are not `Item`, they are of the type `MapItem`.
Just setting the `Map` as their parent isn't enough to display them in the `Map`.

You also need to call [`addMapItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-map.html#addMapItem-method) :

```
sprite = component.createObject(map);
map.addMapItem(sprite);
```

There are alternatives ways to create QML object dynamically, and I believe they are better since it involves less imperative javascript and is more readable.

---

The first one is doing it with a declaratively created [`Component`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) (you can do it directly in your main.qml)  :

```
Component {
    id: mapCircleComponent
    MapCircle { //instead of defining it inline, you can also set the source property to point to another file
        radius: 80000
        color: 'blue'
    }
}

MouseArea {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
        var circle = mapCircleComponent.createObject(map, {"center.latitude" : coord.latitude, "center.longitude": coord.longitude});
        map.addMapItem(circle);
    }
}
```

---

The other way is to do it with [model and views](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-modelview.html), and it's my favorite since you are not directly dealing with component and object instantiation.

Since we are not dealing with `Item` here, the usual `ListView` or `Repeater` won't work here. We need to use [`MapItemView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtlocation-mapitemview.html):

```
ListModel {
    id: mapModel
}

Map {
    id: map
    //...
    MapItemView {
        model: mapModel
        delegate: MapCircle {
            radius: 80000
            color: 'blue'
            center {
                latitude: lat
                longitude: longi
            }
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            var coord = map.toCoordinate(Qt.point(mouse.x,mouse.y))
            mapModel.append({lat : coord.latitude, longi: coord.longitude});
        }
    }
}
```

In the `onClicked` we just append a row to the model and the `MapItemView` automatically instantiates a `MapCircle` for each row and add it to the `Map`.

Comment: Thanks! your answer is really helpful. I assume with your second solution, it is possible to manipulate (remove, change the value, or add new data) the model right? But, once I manipulate the model, how can I update the MapItemView?

Comment: Correct. The `MapItemView` will update itself if you modify your model.

Comment: If I change MapCircle to MapPolyline and use the coord for the path, do you know how can I use 'addCoordinate()' method?